# Is it possible to emit a signal from the baseclass of a derived object using "this"

Tags: qt, inheritance, signals-slots

Not too sure how to formulate my question and I hope that this is more clear. I want to have a baseclass that looks something like this:

```
class Base : public QObject { 
    Q_OBJECT


    void doSomething() { emit test(this); }

    virtual void doSomethingElse() = 0;

signals:
     void test(Base*);
}
```

And then in the derived class do this:

```
 class Derived : public Base {

     void doSomethingElse() { emit test(this); }

 }
```

If I now listen to the signals of this object and do I listen to test(Derived*) or/and test(Base*)?

Comment: And can you concrete the mean of "listen" - in this case a lot things depend on it e.g listen - to pass a sender as argument for slot or ... ?

Comment: connect it by "connect(objectInMyExample, SIGNAL(test(Base*/Derived*)), someOtherObject, SLOT(handleObject(Base*/Derived*)))

Comment: Ok so in handleObject(Base*) it will handle Base and in handlObject(Derived*) it will listen Derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moc generates at compile time a list of the slots and signals based on the way you declared them in the classes that use the `Q_OBJECT` macro. 

This list is a list of strings, so if you declared:

```
signals:
     void test(Base*);
```

the item in the list would be the string `"test(Base*)"` (you can see that list in the variable `qt_meta_YourClass` of the file `moc_yourclass.cpp` in the output directory).

The macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` also return strings, `connect()` canonize them so they are formatted like the one from the moc generated list, and compares them to those in that list.

When you derive the class, the string hasn't changed, so you still have to use `SIGNAL(test(Base*))`.

Comment: should i make the signal virtual? or is it better to cast from the baseclass ->derived class instead of using sender and cast from QOBject to base/derived class?

Comment: Technically yes, even though the moc will give you a warning. And the C++ doesn't support covariant or contravariant parameters, so `test(Base*)` and `test(Derived*)` would be unrelated. You can still avoid casting by doing the part that depend on the object being `Base*` or `Derived*` in the object itself through a virtual function or by using a visitor pattern.

Comment: hm. so if i understand you correcty, if my functions in the baseclass are virtual it doesnt matter if i get a pointer to the Base*, I would still get the virtual functions etc.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include senders as parameters of signals. You can simply use `QObject::sender()` to get the `QObject` that has sent the signal.

eg:

```
emit test();
```

Then in a slot:

```
void Listener::someObject_test() {
    QObject* sender = QObject::sender();
    // or:
    Derived* sender = (Derived*)QObject::sender();
}
```

Comment: i thought that the documentation was agaist sender()?

Comment: I used it several times and never got any problem with it. The documentation states "This function violates the object-oriented principle of modularity". If you provide the object as a parameter of the signal, it would also violate the same principle. Sometime it's necessary to know where a signal comes from and, in these cases, using `QObject::sender()` is the simplest way.

Comment: `sender()` isn't free, it locks a mutex and does a list lookup. If you pass the object as parameter of the signal, it indicates, semantically, that the object is part of the message, you don't have to use a cast to use your object and it also works when the signal and the slot belong to different threads unlike `sender()`. As a bonus, you can even emit the signal with an object as parameter that isn't the sender.

Comment: @alexidm, thankfully Qt wasn't designed around the concept of each signal sending the sender as a parameter. Otherwise, every time I override a Qt class, I'll have to override (and duplicate) every method that dispatches a signal. Moreover you *always* have to cast an object that you got from `QObject::sender()` since it will always give you a `QObject` (unless you need a QObject, which is rare).

Comment: Finally, I don't believe a list lookup is that slow. You mostly need signal for events generated by the user, which are not that frequent. For anything more frequent, there might be some optimization. Perhaps sending the sender as parameter is an optimization, perhaps there's a better way... But that's a borderline case anyway, which depends on the application.

Comment: I meant that you don't have to cast if you pass the object as a parameter instead of retrieving it through `sender()`... And by "part of the message", that if you know every slots to which you connect a signal will need the `sender()` parameter it is simpler and clearer to pass it as parameter of that signal than using `sender()`.

Comment: Short Warning: The cast might be unsafe unless one is aware of all sources for that signal. Since this targets slot is expecting a specific class, take the efford in just create a Signals from that specific class. In that case the OPs basic approach of emitting >this< is giving a type safe signature and should be prefered.

Answer (score 0):

As the derived class does not have its own signal, you will listen the test(Base*).